# How to increase width of select box arrow?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to increase the width of select box arrow like fa fa caret. i am not getting it how to do. I used img tag inside the each field and given position absolute and adjusted with left top properties but i think this is not proper way of doing this and even i click on the image arrow not select options are opening so i removed this. Please tell me proper solution for it.

```css
.search-categories{
    background: #E40444 !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style type="text/css">
    
    </style>

    <div class="col-md-12 ">
      <div class="row">
       <form action="#" method="get" id="search_mini_form">
          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-2 catnames">
             <select name="cat" class="form-control search-categories">
                <option>Categories</option>
                <option value="3">abcd</option>
                <option value="4">abcd</option>
                <option value="5">abcd</option>
             </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-2 catnames catnames-arrow ">
             <select name="cat" class="form-control search-categories search-Hourly">
                <option>Hourly</option>
                <option value="3">abcd</option>
                <option value="4">abcd</option>
                <option value="5">abcd</option>
             </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 catquery ">
       <div class="input-group">
             <input type="search" class="form-control " name="q" id="location" value="" maxlength="128" placeholder="Search Place..." autocomplete="off" />
         <div class="input-group-addon catsubmit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete"></div>
       </form>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the css triangle to make the arrow.

**HTML**

```
<div class="selectwrap">
      <select>
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 3</option>
        <option>Option 4</option>
      </select>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
select {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 34px;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
}

.selectwrap {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.selectwrap:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;  
  border-top: 8px solid #000;
  right: 4px;
  top: 14px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very complicated to style form elements cross-browser because very browser has different look for form elements (especially checkbox, radio, select, progress).

I suggest using some plugin like [select2](https://select2.github.io/) so you can easily style very element browser-independent.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').select2({
    width: '200px'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://select2.github.io/select2/select2-3.5.3/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://select2.github.io/select2/select2-3.5.3/select2.js"></script>


<select>
  <option>Op 1</option>
  <option>Op 2</option>
  <option>Op 3</option>
  <option>Op 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: sorry to say but how this answer is related to op's question? he asked to increase the width of arrow of select box but not any plugin. Please don't change the moto/aim of op's question. Thank you

Comment: @Leothelion I suggest way to increase width of element instead of banging your head against wall for hours.

Answer (score 0):

better use some select element customisation plugin like  [select2](https://select2.github.io/), [selectize](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/). The appearance that these plugins create can be customised through css.

You cannot fully control the appearance of `select` element in cross browser manner with css alone.

Comment: please upvote my question because i am not able to upvote on your answer because of low reputation.